# if inside a for whats wrong with it?

Tags: java

```
for(int i =0; i<8;i++){
  for(int j =0; j<8;j++){
    Ratsuk.getNewtablero().getMesa(i,j).setBackground(matrizcolor[i][j]);
    if (Ratsuk.getNewtablero().getMesa(i,j).getBackground()==Color.lightGray);
    Ratsuk.getNewtablero().getMesa(i,j).setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

`Ratsuk.getNewtablero().getMesa(i,j)` is for calling an a JButton 2d array that is inside newtablero and matrizcolor is a 2d array of colors of the same size.

when it runs this all the buttons in that array are disable not only the lightgray ones. Can any 1 explain me why?

Comment: If you can fix the indentation, it would help us see what is going on here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo question

Comment: yes my bad I made a really stupid mistake -_-

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the inner if-statement.

```
if (Ratsuk.getNewtablero().getMesa(i,j).getBackground()==Color.lightGray);
```

This causes the next line to execute every time. Remember that the compiler will associate either (1) a single statement or (2) a single block with any if-statement. In this case, the compiler is associating a single statement with that if-statement, but the single statement is merely a semicolon that literally does nothing. After the semicolon statement "executes", the program continues as normal by executing the next line:

```
Ratsuk.getNewtablero().getMesa(i,j).setEnabled(false);
```

Regardless of true or false value of the if-statement. Remove the semicolon and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: And use `equals` to compare Colors.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think if will be removed in optimization phase, but I am Not sure.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I suspect not, unless the compiler can determine definitely that no method in the call chain has any side effects.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson hmm got it, Does optimization consider standard library functions are called with some flag options **?**